# Has anyone used the wordpress plugin w3-total-cache on a Dreamhost VPS successfully?

Tags: hosting, server, plugin-w3-total-cache, optimization

I was encouraged by Dreamhost to go with FCGI, XCache and w3 total cache. But I'm not sure what the optimal settings are, especially re: the Object and Database cache. Any suggestions?

Also, I can't get this error message to go away: `Recently an error occurred while creating the CSS / JS minify cache` Nor can I get log files to show up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Recently an error occurred while creating the CSS / JS minify cache...

Frederick Townes, the developer of W3 Total Cache, [himself said](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-recently-an-error-occurred-while-creating-the-css-js-minify-cache?replies=30#post-2636327) that the notifications "functionality really gives too many false positives right now and should be disabled." That was 4 months ago, and still holds true today.

I have this very same error showing up on some of my setups, but the rest are fine, and all this happens on the very same server.

So, I'm afraid, this IS a false positive.

Comment: I also have the same error, and almost 2 years later...

Comment: @NickNo As stated in the answer, it'd be a false positive.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not, since the css isn't displaying correctly after seeing this error. Not sure why it appears, I can flush and change query string variable and error will go away and all will look nice, but within 24-48 hours i see error back in admin area and design breaks. I am gonna compare css/live code on a char by char basis between working and broken, and see what's going on.

Comment: Hmm... weird. I am no longer using W3 Total Cache for minification though. I am doing file concatenation using Apache: https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/src/.htaccess#L711